# How to direct load to web folder

Tags: php, yii2

I have just installed Yii2. I am still new in this framework. When I created new project using composer named "Sample-Yii2", I must open "web" folder to load index.php. I am just curious if this index.php can be moved to root folder. But it cant.

How I can get direct page when I open localhost/Sample-Yii2 instead loacalhost/Sample-Yii2/web?

Comment: Create virtual host! http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: Is there the other way? like modify the config?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following configuration in `Apache's httpd.conf` file or within a virtual host configuration. Note that you should replace `path/to/basic/web` with the actual path for `basic/web`.

```
# Set document root to be "basic/web"
DocumentRoot "path/to/basic/web"

<Directory "path/to/basic/web">
    # use mod_rewrite for pretty URL support
    RewriteEngine on
    # If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # Otherwise forward the request to index.php
    RewriteRule . index.php
    # ...other settings...
</Directory>
```

Reference [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/start-installation.md). Also read the [article](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/755/how-to-hide-frontend-web-in-url-addresses-on-apache/).

Answer (score 0):

If you use apache as a web server in development, you should simply properly configure a virtual host in apache config files as described in other . May be it does not worth it. For example if you are just playing around with the new framework (Yii2). Try to use PHP's Built-in Server instead. It's much simpler to use.

1. `cd Sample-Yii2/web`
2. `php -S localhost:8000`
3. Go to your browser and visit `localhost:8000`

For more details see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)